# How to modify the code so that Highcharts graph does not cover fixed navigation bar at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I would like to have a fixed navigation bar at the top of the page. For this I have used [this approach as described on w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp).

However, it does not work when I add highchart javascript graph on page. Please have a look [at the following jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hladky_jiri/90sth59u/). When I scroll the page, javascript will cover the navigation bar.

I insert javascript graph like this:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
```

Could somebody please advice how to fix the code so that javascript/highchart graph does not cover the navigation bar when scrolling?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Increase menu's z-index or decrease container's z-index.

```
    z-index: 999;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/90sth59u/1/